# how to indent just first line in ntheorem package

Tags: ntheorem

I am writing a book and faced a problem with non-standard names of theorems and problems, which I solved with the help of the ntneorem package, but the standard indentation of the first line was removed. How to return it?

I also looked at the amsthm package, but did not find how to solve the problem with the name.
My code:

```
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\theoremheaderfont{\normalfont\bfseries} 
\theorembodyfont{\itshape}
\theoremseparator{.}
\theorempreskipamount1cm
\theorempreskip{0pt}
\theorempostskip{0pt}
\theoremnumbering{arabic}
\theoremsymbol{}
```

[image]

Theoremindent indent all theorem text. Which I don't want.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{ntheorem}
\theoremheaderfont{\indent\normalfont\bfseries} % Here's the trick!
\theorembodyfont{\itshape}
\theoremseparator{.}
\theorempreskipamount1cm
\theorempreskip{0pt}
\theorempostskip{0pt}
\theoremnumbering{arabic}
\theoremsymbol{}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{theorem}
\lipsum[1]
\end{theorem}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh my god, was it so easy and obvious? I am even ashamed of the question, even though I have been tormented by the solution for many days. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can patch `\@thm` to set `\itemindent` the same as `\parindent`, so every theorem will be affected.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@thm}{\trivlist}{\trivlist\itemindent\parindent}{}{}
\makeatother

\theorembodyfont{\itshape}
\theoremseparator{.}
\theorempreskip{0pt}
\theorempostskip{0pt}
\theoremnumbering{arabic}
\theoremsymbol{}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-4]

\begin{theorem}
\lipsum[2][1-3]
\end{theorem}

\lipsum[3][1-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that setting `\theorempreskipamount` does nothing and is deprecated.